# Why BFS to get shortest path?

Tags: graph-algorithm, shortest-path, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

> BFS has the extremely useful property that if all of the edges in a
>   graph are unweighted (or the same weight) then the first time a node
>   is visited is the shortest path to that node from the source node.

How this property can be verified? why not in case of DFS such property holds?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, you should first understand how BFS and DFS work in a general sense.

Consider a binary search tree, which is just a very simple graph, as shown below:

```
        *a
       /  \
    *b     *c
   /  \   /  \
  *d  *e *f   *g
```

***Breadth First Search (BFS)***, as its name implies, will first explore the nodes closest to the source node. Suppose you start your search from node *a, the BFS algorithm will first explore *b, following *c, and then *d, *e, *f, *g.

***Depth First Search (DFS)***, on the other hand, go depth first. From the source node *a, you will expore *b, and then *d, *e (until you reach the end pretty much).

Hence, the statement:

> ... the first time a node is visited is the shortest path to that node from the source node

Suppose, as the BFS is running, you visited node *b. This is indeed the shortest path from the source node to node *b, because BFS has the property of always exploring the nodes that are closest to the source node first.

Similar concepts can be applied for a more complex graphs. They all work the same.

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
  * A
 /  \
|    \
|     \
* B    \
 \      \
  \      \
   \      \
    * D    \
     \      \
      \______* C
```

Take a look at this simple graph.
If you would do DFS starting from A, for example, and the first neighbour visited will be vertex B, then the first time you'll visit vertex C will be through D, so you'll get a path of length 3.

So, when A will look for his other neighbour (C) he won't visit it, and A-B-D-C is definitely not the shortest path from A to C.